# What is the main difference between computed and mounted in vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**when i add** `computed()` **instead** `mounted()` **it throws an error**

```
export default {
  components: {
    MainLayout
  },
  mounted(){
    var x = document.getElementById('homeTabPanes');
    // x.style.background = "blue";
    console.log("check the value of x", x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad) is an object containing methods that returns data, [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) is a life hook executed after the instance gets mounted, check out the links to the docs it have really good explanation

Answer (score 3):

From the [`docs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

> ..computed properties are cached based on their dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.

If you want data to be cached use Computed properties on the other hand `mounted` is a *lifecycle* hook, a method which is called as soon as the Vue instance is ***mounted*** on the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

In-template expressions are very convenient, but they are meant for simple operations. Putting too much logic in your templates can make them bloated and hard to maintain.
That’s why for any complex logic, you should use a computed property.

## Basic Example

```
<div id="reverseMessageContainer">
  <p>Original message: "{{ message }}"</p>
  <p>Computed reversed message: "{{ reversedMessage }}"</p>
</div>
```

look at the js below:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#reverseMessageContainer',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    reversedMessage: function () {
      // `this` points to the vm instance
      return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

Here we have declared a computed property *reversedMessage*. The function we provided will be used as the **getter function** for the property *vm.reversedMessage:*

You can open the console and play with the example vm yourself. The value of vm.reversedMessage is always dependent on the value of vm.message.

```
console.log(vm.reversedMessage) // => 'olleH'
vm.message = 'Goodbye'
console.log(vm.reversedMessage) // => 'eybdooG'
```

For more better understanding you can visit
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html